# If $1 \sim 2$ and $2 \sim 3$, how is $\sim$ an equivalence relation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm asked to describe an equivalence relation on $S \in \{1,2,3,4\}$ where $1 \sim 2$ and $2 \sim 3$.

However I'm a little confused over why this qualifies as an equivalence relation, since through the symmetry property $1 \sim 2 \iff 2 \sim 1$, and so $2 \in cl(1)$. We also know that since $2 \sim 3$, $2 \in cl(3)$.

This means that $2$ exists inside two equivalence classes, and so the equivalence classes of $S$ don't form a partition of $S$.

Can someone clear up where I've gone wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: What if there's just one equivalence class?

Comment: @naslundx: or two, one with three elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your reasoning is fine, up to a point: what you've shown is that strictly having $1\sim 2$ and $2\sim3$ is not enough to form an equivalence relation.

But they aren't asking you to show that $\{(1,2),(2,3)\}$ is an equivalence relation -- they're asking you to find AN equivalence relation such that these two relations hold.

For transitivity to be satisfied, if we have both $1\sim 2$ and $2\sim 3$, then necessarily we must have $1\sim 3$.

What conditions must be satisfied, in addition to $1\sim 3$, in order for $\sim$ to be reflexive and symmetric as well?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the push in the right direction. The question actually asked me to show that there are 2 possibilities for $\sim$. I have that if any one of the elements $\{1,2,3\}$ is related to $4$, then $\sim$ is an equivalence relation with partition $\{1,2,3,4\}$. Otherwise none of the first three elements is related to $4$, which means that $\sim$ is a relation with partitions $\{1,2,3\}\{4\}$.

Comment: @Jake You got it.  The conditions $1\sim 2$ and $2\sim 3$ tell us that no matter what, $1,2,3$ are in the same equivalence class.  The only question then, is whether or not $4$ is in that same class.

Answer (score 0):

Just take as the required equivalence relation: $$ \forall x,y \in \{1,2,3,4\} \quad x \sim y   \quad !$$